# Connecting to secured remote AEM repository

Tags: aem, jcr

In order to create JCR nodes, We are trying to programmatically connect to a remote AEM instance using the `JcrUtils.getRepository(...)` method to acquire the handle to the repository instance.

This instance is secured and checks for a cookie in the request to let the user in.

Is there a way to pass the cookie to `JcrUtils` (or other methods of connecting to an AEM repository)?

Right now, when running the code  `JcrUtils.getRepository("http://host:port/crx/server");` it just throws the following exception:

```
    javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to access a repository with the following settings:
    org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: https://<host>:<port>/crx/server
The following RepositoryFactory classes were consulted:
    org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2dav.Jcr2davRepositoryFactory: declined
    org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.Jcr2spiRepositoryFactory: declined
    org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JndiRepositoryFactory: declined
    org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryFactoryImpl: declined
    org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.RmiRepositoryFactory: failed
because of RemoteRuntimeException: java.rmi.RemoteException: Failed to read the resource at URL https://<host>:<port>/crx/server; nested exception is: 
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C21444F
because of RemoteException: Failed to read the resource at URL https://<host>:<port>/crx/server; nested exception is: 
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C21444F
because of StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C21444F
Perhaps the repository you are trying to access is not available at the moment.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils.getRepository(JcrUtils.java:223)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils.getRepository(JcrUtils.java:263)
...
```

Comment: Can you hit "https://<host>:<port>/crx/server" in browser and check if that loads ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass cookie via `JcrUtils.getRepository(...)` it accepts [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) as a string.

In your logs looks like **org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2dav.Jcr2davRepositoryFactory** doesn't exist in application classpath.
Make sure you added to dependencies following libs

- jackrabbit-jcr-commons
- jackrabbit-jcr2dav

in case you are using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr2dav</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting similar issue as @user3239244 but only in case of https.
I am trying to access repository from standalone java application

```
repository = JcrUtils.getRepository(url)
```

Works for `http` and fails for `https`

From logs:

> javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to access a repository with the
>   following settings:
>       org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: https://localhost:5433/crx/server The following RepositoryFactory
>   classes were consulted:
>       org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2dav.Jcr2davRepositoryFactory: declined
>       org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.Jcr2spiRepositoryFactory: declined
>       org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JndiRepositoryFactory: declined
>       org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryFactoryImpl: declined
>       org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.RmiRepositoryFactory: failed
>           because of RepositoryException: Failed to read the resource at URL https://localhost:5433/crx/server
>           because of SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>           because of ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>           because of SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target